# How to distinguish the cause of wavelength and frequency change?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-entanglement, quantum-gravity, wormholes

In the theory of relativity, wavelength and frequency will change due to space-time geometry; in quantum mechanics, wavelength and frequency will change due to energy radiation, so how to distinguish whether the change of wavelength and frequency is due to space-time geometry or energy radiation?

Take the frequency of electrons as an example:

[image]

The change in electron frequency may be due to gravitational redshift:

[image]

[image]

The change in electron frequency may be due to particle radiation:

[image]

[image]

How to distinguish whether the change in electron frequency is caused by gravitational redshift or particle radiation?

This should be a very basic question for ER=EPR and GR=QM.

Answer (score 0):

You know if you observe a frequency at your place with fixed gravity or if you observe it coming from a distant object with different gravity.
we assume the the same atoms at different places have the same energy spectra.

Comment: We know because we usually measure with light and light is not deflected by electromagnetism.
However, if we use electrons to measure like an electron microscope and the object to be measured has the same mass-to-charge ratio as electrons, how can we identify the cause of the change?

Comment: I can't understand your question. first what do you mean with "the object to be measured has the same mass-to-charge ratio as electrons" of what objects do you think?. how do you come to different gravities?

Comment: If we use light to measure, we can clearly know that the change of energy and momentum is due to the geometry of space-time.

However, if we measure with electrons, can we still know that the changes in energy and momentum are due to the geometry of space-time rather than electromagnetic interactions as clearly as we measure with light?

Comment: For example, if the electron microscope image changes, it could be because of an uncharged massive object or a positively charged object nearby.
Can we judge whether the object is an uncharged massive object or a positively charged object by the change of the image?

Comment: you would realize a "massive object" is near by!

Comment: That's why I say "the same mass-to-charge ratio as electrons".
If you have the same mass-to-charge ratio as an electron, can you still distinguish between electromagnetism and gravitation?

Comment: Why is gravity a fictitious force but electromagnetism is not?
Does the paradox of charged particle radiation in a gravitational field imply that the electromagnetic force can also be a fictitious force?

Comment: "Why is gravity a fictitious force" who stated this?

Comment: Gravity is considered to be equivalent to the inertial force of an accelerating frame of reference, and the inertial force is considered to be a virtual force.